# Java: Add elements ArrayList

Tags: java, generics, arraylist, nullpointerexception

I have this code that tells me a `NullPointerException` precisely at the method `inizializza()` at line:

```
valori[y].add(new Record(matriceBinaria[i][j], j));
```

How can I add items to the `valori` without that kind of exception?

[Code java](http://pastebin.com/xuxA3hCP)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must also initialize each element in you array as follows :

```
if (valori[y] == null)
    valori[y] = new ArrayList();

valori[y].add(new Record(matriceBinaria[i][j], j));
```

`ArrayList[size]` is actually an array where each element is the `ArrayList` object. Since `ArrayList` is not a primitive you must alloacte memory for it by using `new`. So when you do `valori[y]` in your code you are accessing an uninitialized (null) object

Comment: Thanks! How do I create an iterator over "matriceBinaria"? I have set as follows: http://pastebin.com/Lbs6bWuj  but I get "ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException" and I print only the first values ​​of "valori" set to null!